# Odoo models inherits model changing defaults

Tags: model, odoo, odoo-8

I'm trying to change default value of a field of an inherit model.
The model I'm trying to change is account.invoice like this:

```
class account_invoice(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'account.invoice'

    defaults = {
        'journal_id': None,
    }
```

the reason is that the client have several journals and is afraid that some employee forget to change to the correct journal. I need to select it manually

EDIT: 
I'm using this code but _default_currency is not override

```
from openerp import fields, models, osv, api, _
from openerp.osv import osv,fields as Fields


TYPE2JOURNAL = {
    'out_invoice': 'sale',
    'in_invoice': 'purchase',
    'out_refund': 'sale_refund',
    'in_refund': 'purchase_refund',
}

class account_invoice(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'account.invoice'

    @api.model
    def _default_journal(self):        
        return None 

    @api.model
    def _default_currency(self):
        inv_type = self._context.get('type', 'out_invoice')
        inv_types = inv_type if isinstance(inv_type, list) else [inv_type]
        company_id = self._context.get('company_id', self.env.user.company_id.id)
        domain = [
            ('type', 'in', filter(None, map(TYPE2JOURNAL.get, inv_types))),
            ('company_id', '=', company_id),
        ]        
        journal = self.env['account.journal'].search(domain, limit=1) 
        return journal.currency or journal.company_id.currency_id
```

Answer (score 0):

The default on the original py is defined as a function called _default_journal

```
@api.model
def _default_journal(self):
    inv_type = self._context.get('type', 'out_invoice')
    inv_types = inv_type if isinstance(inv_type, list) else [inv_type]
    company_id = self._context.get('company_id', self.env.user.company_id.id)
    domain = [
        ('type', 'in', filter(None, map(TYPE2JOURNAL.get, inv_types))),
        ('company_id', '=', company_id),
    ]
    return self.env['account.journal'].search(domain, limit=1)
```

just redefine it and put "None" in the return.

Else, you can re-define the field:

```
journal_id = fields.Many2one('account.journal', string='Journal',
    required=True, readonly=True, states={'draft': [('readonly', False)]},
    default=_default_journal,
    domain="[('type', 'in', {'out_invoice': ['sale'], 'out_refund': ['sale_refund'], 'in_refund': ['purchase_refund'], 'in_invoice': ['purchase']}.get(type, [])), ('company_id', '=', company_id)]")
```

just copy the same and delete the line with the default.

Take care if you do the first solution, because the default currency is taken from the default journal:

```
@api.model
def _default_currency(self):
    journal = self._default_journal()
    return journal.currency or journal.company_id.currency_id
```

be sure to redefine this function aswell parsing the code of default journal to get the currency that you need.

Comment: I successful override def _default_journal to return None, but when I try to do it to def _default_currency the function is call from the original model, I get the error on the account_invoice model from odoo path.

Comment: Wanna show me the code? be sure that the dependences in __openerp__.py are defined aswell the model you are inheriting. Plus be sure that it is the only module re-defining it.

Anyway, try to call super so you dont break the integrity, just change the return.

Comment: I append the code editing the originals post, to debug I append print on the first line of def _default_currency, but is never print so the function is never call, besides I get nonetype object doesn't have .currency in the originals odoo account_invoice.py file

Comment: Do you have the dependence on the __openerp__.py file to Account?.

Obviously you will get nonetype since:

in the last line of the function you have "journal = self._default_journal()" and you are returning in that function...

Add logger to debug instead of print

Comment: Sorry "journal = self._default_journal()" was a typo mistake, in the code I have it ok:
        journal = self.env['account.journal'].search(domain, limit=1)
        return journal.currency or journal.company_id.currency_id

I get :
 File "/opt/PycharmProjects/odoo-8.0/addons/account/account_invoice.py", line 84, in _default_currency
    return journal.currency or journal.company_id.currency_id
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'currency'

I've account in depence, the _default_journal is thowing a None as return so is overriding ok

Comment: The function seems right now, what we need is to log a bit to see what is missing. Try to do a log of inv_type since it may be a context problem. Do the same with the company and the domain to show what is the search

Comment: 2016-02-19 19:53:51,157 14961 INFO prince openerp.addons.client_PRINCE.models: inv_types: ['out_invoice']
2016-02-19 19:53:51,157 14961 INFO prince openerp.addons.client_PRINCE.models: company_id: 1
2016-02-19 19:53:51,157 14961 INFO prince openerp.addons.client_PRINCE.models: domain: [('type', 'in', ['sale']), ('company_id', '=', 1)]
2016-02-19 19:53:51,157 14961 INFO prince openerp.addons.client_PRINCE.models: journal: account.journal(4,)

this work on the _default_journal on _default_currency is never call

Comment: is it the log of the currency function?

Comment: Ok, what you should do then is: Check the database structure of account.invoice model in Configuration > Database structure > Models, check what modules inherit from invoice. Then, search in that modules if any one inherits from the same function, thats why it may not be called yours